# LDAPS : Simple bind failed

Tags: java, ssl, ldap

I'm facing issue connecting to LDAPS from my application. I have imported all necessary certificates on JRE keystore.

I'm able to make calls to LDAPs when I put the following string in java.security

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD5, SSLv3, DSA, RSA keySize < 2048
```

When I change this line to

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD5, DSA, DESede, DES_CBC, DHE, RC4, SSLv3, ECDH_anon, DH_anon, NULL, DH keySize < 768, RSA keySize < 2048
```

my connection fails with following error:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: testxxxxl.xxxx.com:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Socket closed]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:218)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2740)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:316)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:211)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:122)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:709)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:431)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:404)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(LdapClient.java:358)
```

In wireshark it complains about certificate invalid.My question is if my certificate is invalid, it shouldn't be working with this line as well.

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD5, SSLv3, DSA, RSA keySize < 2048
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Sounds like the client and server are unable to negotiate a cipher suite. When you disable the algorithms then a they are able to. There have been some issues of this type of activity when the client and server are different versions of Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a secure connection to the LDAP server and you see an error like the following when trying to connect to Active Directory:
simple bind failed: ad.hostname.com:636
Import the LDAP server public certificate directly into the Klocwork keystore (which should be_jvm\lib\security\cacerts).
This causes the certificate validation process at the Klocwork end to be bypassed, since you have decided to trust the LDAP server certificate by importing it into your list of trusted certificates.

Ask your LDAP administrator to set this extension of your LDAP server certificate to non-critical.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. We did import to cacerts as well. Still doesn't work. I'm confused how the disabled algorithms parameter has some impact on this.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Java the TLSv1 has been disabled.
In my case this happened when upgrading from Java 8 to Java 11.
Re-enabling TLSv1 helped. It is as easy as defining property:

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1
```

Of course you can need also other protocols, so you can specify full list:

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
```